# Can't connect to SharePoint data source using lightswitch

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I am trying to connect a share point data source to my light switch Project but it shows some errors like

> `http://www.server.net/_vti_bin/listdata.svc` does not appear to be a valid site. SharePoint 2010 (or later) with an installation of WCF Data Services is required.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

While adding SharePoint Site address in Enter Connection Information page, please provide the SharePoint site URL without the 'default.aspx' and try.

Comment: thank you for your response i just enter url like http://www.server.net  but not connecting we need install anything in share point ?

Comment: nothing specific in Sharepoint but you need to have couple of stuff in your Dev machine. Please refer to this link.http://www.schaeflein.net/Pages/SharePoint-2013-REST-and-WCF-Data-Services.aspx

Comment: i am a beginner in share point , i am trying to access share point data source from a remote server.do i need share point installed on my system ?

Comment: You dont need to have sharepoint installed in you system. if you have proper privileges and required software in your development box as explained in the link above. you shoudl be all set.